# Angular-Meteor package on Android device is throwing "Unexpected token <"

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, android-studio, meteor

I was able to run my Angular-Meteor Cordova application no problem until I made a minor change. Now whenever I run `meteor run android-device` it tries to start the application on the device but when it starts has trouble loading the packages. This is the log out put:

```
=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/     
=> Started app on Android Device.             
I20160308-12:51:21.879(0) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/angular_angular.js:1) Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
I20160308-12:51:21.954(0) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/angular_angular-animate.js:32) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noop' of undefined
I20160308-12:51:21.955(0) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/angular_angular-sanitize.js:42) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$$minErr' of undefined
I20160308-12:51:21.955(0) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/angularui_angular-ui-router.js:49) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isDefined' of undefined
I20160308-12:51:22.359(0) (android:http://meteor.local/packages/driftyco_ionic.js:13355) Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
...
```

Oh, I should say this runs on the desktop fine.

**----- Update -----**

I've inspected the WebView with Chrome and weirdly enough the offending file `angular_angular.js` seems to contain HTML! See picture below:

[image: angular_angular.js contains html]

This is totally different from the contents of the same file on the desktop, which contains valid javascript.

Comment: check  illegal character code.

Comment: Hey @IntelliJAmiya, I can check out the code on the desktop, it looks fine, and that works. But how would I check it from my mobile?

Comment: Inspect the WebView using Chrome.

Comment: ooh, didn't know you could do that thanks!

Comment: Interesting. This means that it was either not bundled correctly or something is wrong with the server that runs on your Android device. What was the change that caused this? If you undo the change, do things get back to normal? Do other `js` files show up properly in the dev tools?

Comment: The change that caused this was pretty minor. It was calling a method from a controller and displaying results in the template, which works on the desktop. And yes, it seems all the other js files are fine! Will try upping versions of things or rebuilding if I can.

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting the webview via Chrome I discovered the mobile was using old application files. Answer was to go into the settings -> apps -> myapp and clear the cache/local files.

I thought this would have been expired by meteor but it's not the case. Or perhaps it didn't do it one time because of an error. I'll find out soon enough, but if not I'll have to figure out a way to stop the caching of obsolete files.

Comment: Interesting. However, that makes your issue above hard to reproduce. Could you try and come up with an [mcve] which would allow to reproduce this very issue, and use that in your question? You could then re-focus this entire page on Android's caching issue. I think it would add value and allow future users to relate more easily to your issue. If you want to discuss about it, feel free to create a [chat] room and invite me in.

Comment: Hey Kyll, yeah, in particular I was thinking of creating a separate question for the caching issue.

Comment: That would be a good idea, yep. Then you could flag this one as duplicate of the new one.